# Dereferencing Aliases in LDAP using Spring

Tags: java, spring, ldap, alias, dereference

How to control LDAP Alias Dereferencing Mode using Java and Spring LDAP API?
Similarly to how it is done using *ldapsearch* on linux.

Example:

```
ldapsearch -a never "(&(o=foo)(cn=bar))" cn
ldapsearch -a always "(&(o=foo)(cn=bar))" cn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer my own question.

The following does the job:

```
<bean id="ldapContextSource"
      class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource"
      p:url="${ldap.server.url}">
    <property name="baseEnvironmentProperties">
        <map>
            <entry key="java.naming.ldap.derefAliases" value="never"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```